# What is the priority of bulk flush actions in Flink's Elasticsearch sink?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am following [this](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/elasticsearch.html#configuring-the-internal-bulk-processor) to create an Elasticsearch sink in a Flink application. I want to understand what will be priority if I provide all the values like

```
int FLUSH_MAX_ACTIONS = 10_000;
long FLUSH_INTERVAL_MILLIS = 1_000;
int FLUSH_MAX_SIZE_MB = 1;

esSinkBuilder.setBulkFlushMaxActions(FLUSH_MAX_ACTIONS);
esSinkBuilder.setBulkFlushInterval(FLUSH_INTERVAL_MILLIS);
esSinkBuilder.setBulkFlushMaxSizeMb(FLUSH_MAX_SIZE_MB);
esSinkBuilder.setBulkFlushBackoff(true);
```

In this case, I specified to flush

1. If time interval has crossed 1second
2. If size of buffer is 1MB
3. If there are 10,000 records waiting in buffer

As I am specifying all three at once, what will be the result, which one takes precedence ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whichever limit is reached first triggers the flush. This is handled by `org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkProcessor`.